# How to install Canon MP459 on Ubuntu 16.04 (libtiff4 dependency but libtiff5 already installed)

Tags: drivers, dpkg, printing, dependencies, canon

**I want to install my mp495 x64 driver**, which I downloaded from Canon **on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine**.

> sudo dpkg -i cnijfilter-mp495series_3.40-1_amd64.deb

This shows the following error:

> dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cnijfilter-mp495series:
>
> cnijfilter-mp495series depends on libtiff4 libtiff4-dev; however:
>
> Package libtiff4 is not installed

When I try to install libtiff4, I get:

> Unable to locate package libtiff4

When I try to install it via a downloaded deb file, I get the error:

> that libtiff5 is already installed

I can't uninstall libtiff5 as loads of system tools depend on it.

**How can I force the driver to use the libtiff5 package instead?**

Comment: I found the solution to my own problem, the other questions/answers I found online did not solve it for me, so I want to post it here so that I can bookmark it when I reinstall the system elsewhere (don't have the rep for a answer, thus I have to put it as a comment):

Comment: **(1)** `dpkg-deb -x cnijfilter-mp495series_*_amd64.deb tmp`     **(2)** `dpkg-deb --control cnijfilter-mp495series_*_amd64.deb tmp/DEBIAN`    **(3)** `nano tmp/DEBIAN/control` and replace libtiff4 with libtiff5     **(4)** `dpkg -b tmp/ fixed.deb`       **(5)** `dpkg -i fixed.deb`     **(6)** re-plugin the printer. **Done**

Comment: If this does not work (e.g. the printer is not correctly installed / ignoring tasks) then **(1)** use the libtiff dependencies from [HERE](https://mun-steiner.de/wordpress/index.php/linux/scannen-und-drucken/canon-software-pixma-mg5250/libtiff4-erforderlich/) and  reinstall the canon printer manually: **(2)** extract the downloaded tar archive and `cd cnijfilter-mp495series-*-deb/packages` **(3)** `dpkg -i cnijfilter-common_*_amd64.deb` **(3)** `dpkg -i cnijfilter-mp495series_*_amd64.deb` **(4)** go to "printers" & readd the printer. You should now have the network and local printer installed!

Comment: I migrated your solution to a community wiki answer. Remove the comments if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Prelude:**

The author found the solution to his own problem. The other questions/answers he found online did not solve it for him, so he wants to post it here so that he can bookmark it for easy access when he reinstalls a system elsewhere (The author didn't had the rep for a answer, thus he had to put it as comments).

**Solution:**

1. use the libtiff dependencies from [HERE](https://mun-steiner.de/wordpress/index.php/linux/scannen-und-drucken/canon-software-pixma-mg5250/libtiff4-erforderlich/) and reinstall the canon printer manually:
2. extract the downloaded tar archive and `cd cnijfilter-mp495series-*-deb/packages`
3. `dpkg -i cnijfilter-common_*_amd64.deb`
4. go to "printers" & read the printer.

If this does not work (e.g. the printer is not correctly installed or is  ignoring tasks) then

1. `dpkg-deb -x cnijfilter-mp495series_*_amd64.deb tmp`
2. `dpkg-deb --control cnijfilter-mp495series_*_amd64.deb tmp/DEBIAN`
3. `nano tmp/DEBIAN/control` and replace libtiff4 with libtiff5
4. `dpkg -b tmp/ fixed.deb`
5. `dpkg -i fixed.deb`
6. re-plugin the printer. Done

You should now have the network and local printer installed!

Comment: The second one should be tried first. Thanks for adding the answer!

Comment: @B.L.: Is everything right now?

Comment: Worked again :) just (1) installed the libtiff4 deb (2) downloaded the driver from (canon)[https://www.canon.de/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mp_series/pixma_mp495.aspx?type=drivers&language=&os=Linux%20(64-bit)], extracted it, (3) executed `./cnijfilter-mp495series-3.40-1-deb/install` (4) followed the instructions - that was it

Comment: sorry, was too fast: both, method 1 & 2 don't work anymore :(

Comment: For the record: (1) I downloaded http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100236305.html and tried to install: unmet dependencies (2) I added the ppa: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon`: no packages for xenial (3) I executed `sudo apt install cnijfilter-mp495series` anyway: already installed, unmet dependencies (4) `sudo apt-get -f install` fixed it and now my printer is found automatically & works! Finally! maybe only (3), (4) would have been necessary.